# Insert Single Double Quote Into Start of First Line in Text File

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a file like with a missing double quote at the start...

> ```
> 1","abc","123"
> "2","abcd","456"
> "3","abce","789"
> ```

I want to run a command to insert a single double quote in to the first position so the file looks like...

> ```
> "1","abc","123"
> "2","abcd","456"
> "3","abce","789"
> ```

Comment: At first: [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/) Then: what is your question? this post is nothing but a task request; please read the [tour] ans learn [ask] here!

Comment: Apologises I have removed "Windows" from the tag

Comment: So you are really working on MS-DOS?? You do not use Windows??

Comment: I need to be able to do this via running a command via cmd.exe

Comment: You have "a file" - one single file? Why do you need a batch script then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow I miss the point, why you need a batch script to change a single file. But here you go:

```
@echo off
<nul >"new.txt" set /p x="""
>>"new.txt" type "old.txt"
move /y "old.txt" "new.txt"
```

first: write a `"` without linebreak ((mis)using `set /p`)
second: add the original file
third: rename the result to the original filename

Comment: This solution will be put inside a stored procedure run multiple times a day to resolve the issue so it's not just a one-off this info wasn't really relevant to the post....