# Delete Single Double Quote From Last Line of a Text File

Tags: batch-file, cmd

There is always a single double quote at the end of a text file...

```
"1","abc","123"
"2","abcd","456"
"3","abce","789"
"
```

I need a command to run via `cmd.exe` to delete the last line (the single double quote) only...

```
"1","abc","123"
"2","abcd","456"
"3","abce","789"
```

Comment: This may help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/418916/7320612

Answer (score 0):

extended my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44549069/2152082):

```
@echo off
copy t.txt old.txt
<nul >"new.txt" set /p x="""
>>"new.txt" (type "old.txt" |findstr /v "^.$")
rem move /y "old.txt" "new.txt"
type new.txt
```

The additional `findstr /v` excludes lines with a single character (it's quite difficult to work with a `"`, but I guess, a "single character line" is good enough)

Comment: Actually if it makes it any easier code wise it's always the last line in the file....